# Need guidance on solution using phonegap and jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm creating an app using phonegap that pulls the majority of its content from a database. It has a few hundred pages so I thought the best option would be to use a single page solution and just keep loading content into the main div when needed.
I have tried using Handlebars to do this but I'm not sure if that was the best solution as I cant get jquery mobile working with it (the app needs lots of accordions). Have also tried creating my own very simple accordions but failed dismally to even get an onlcick event working within the handlebars script tags.
Can anyone recommend a build that would be good for this job please? Or guide me to some example solutions that are along these lines?
I have googled extensively for 2 days now and have tried quite a few suggestions out but no success so decided to post here. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generate all the content into your div, but using css hide almost all of them. As the user does what needs to be done to activate your paging call the show() function for the first 10 elements, if you consider 10 to be a page.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use List View pattern of jquery

// adding data on list view
$('#list_view').append('<li >' your data '</li>');

//refreshing list
 $("#list_view").listview("refresh");

//removing elements from list
$("#list_view").empty();

You can use multiple div's as well in the list view

use below link for more:
http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/
```